# Creating consecutive words from a string

Tags: strings, ruby

This is a method which creates an array of all possible consecutive substrings from a string:

```
def get_seperated_tokens(query)
  result = []
  length = query.split.count
  tokens = query.downcase.strip.split(' ')
  length.times do |i|
    length.times do |j|
      result << tokens[i..j].join(' ') if j >= i
    end
  end
  result
end
```

To get a better idea I have added rspec for it:

```
describe "#get_seperated_tokens" do
  it "returns an array of seperated tokens" do
    query = 'ruby is awesome'
    result = ['ruby','is', 'awesome', 'ruby is', 'is awesome','ruby is awesome']
    expect(get_seperated_tokens(query)).to include(*result)
  end
  it "returns an array of seperated tokens" do
    query = 'red blue iphones'
    result = ['red','blue', 'iphones', 'red blue', 'blue iphones','red blue iphones']
    expect(get_seperated_tokens(query)).to include(*result)
  end
end
```

How can this be made more idiomatic?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Michael Szyndel mentioned in a comment, `Array#combination` is the more appropriate method to use.

```
def get_separated_tokens query
  tokens = query.split
  (0..tokens.size).to_a.combination(2).map{ |i,j| tokens[i...j].join " " }
end
```

Comment: In fact Michael wrote an answer with `combination` (now deleted), the problem is that OP needs *contiguous* combinations, so this won't do.

Comment: @tokland, I don't get you. Did you run this code? It produces the same as OP's code.

Comment: oh, you're right, you use combinations, but with a slice later, which is right. +1

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)? (my page on the subject: [FP with Ruby](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming)). Your code feels clunky because, well, imperative programming is clunky (recommended reading: [Can Programming Be Liberated From The Von Neumann Style?](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs242/readings/backus.pdf%E2%80%8E)).

You just need to re-write the code without `times` (as it's being used as an `each`), mutable variables (`result = []`), inplace operations (`<<`) and inline conditionals with side-effects (`do_something if j >= i`). I'd write:

```
def get_separated_tokens(query)
  tokens = query.split
  (0...tokens.size).flat_map do |istart|
    (istart...tokens.size).map do |iend|
      tokens[istart..iend].join(" ")
    end
  end
end

p get_separated_tokens("ruby is awesome")
#["ruby", "ruby is", "ruby is awesome", "is", "is awesome", "awesome"]
```

Comment: You can select Nakilon's answer, I calculated the combinations to build ranges, we have Array#combination.